# Is the ball in the Hoops game mode bouncier?

Tags: rocket-league

Across the game types in Rocket League, a different ball is used. In Hoops, the ball takes on the appearance of a basketball, which makes sense. Is this ball bouncier than, say, the normal ball found in Chaos or Standard matches? It seems like it bounces a little bit more since it's a basketball.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the balls are the same in Hoops and Soccar. User MegaChip97 did [some testing](https://www.reddit.com/r/RocketLeague/comments/4gijr1/ok_so_does_the_hoops_ball_bounce_different/d2hu28p/?) to prove this:

> Open up a private game. Drive to the ball until you stand directly infront of it. Backflip once. Boost into the ball.
>
> DO the same thing on Hoops private.
>
> From my experience playing and the test it behaves exactly the same.
>
> You can also airdribble with it which I doubt I would be able to do if it would be any different from the normal ball.
>
> If you want to test the bounciness, just do the same setup and look at its bounces.

As an aside, while searching for a definitive answer, I came across many instances where users admitted that the different shape of the court and the walls definitely may be tricking people into thinking the *ball* itself behaves differently, when really it's the *arena* that's different.